# Should I create a child table without primary key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I'm designing a database with a child table that may contains billions of records in the future. So I try to use less fields (and smaller ones) as possible.

So I'm considering not using a primary key, as it would have to be a bigint, but I will never use it in my queries (this child table won't have ever a 1-N relationship).

Does a primary key useful for something else than query and join ? I suppose Mysql have an other system to distinguish a record from another, or am I wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Edit : my create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `receipt_line` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `receipt_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prod_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `coupon_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `qty` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `receipt_line `
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `id ticket` (`receipt_id`),
  ADD KEY `id produit` (`prod_id`),
  ADD KEY `id coupon` (`coupon_id`),
```

Obviously, the parent table is Ticket, and I have other linked tables (product, coupon).
The id field is linked to nothing. The other keys aren't unique.

Comment: They make it easier to identify specific child records.  Say that a child record needs to be updated later, how will you uniquely identify it for the update statement?

Comment: I wont update the records. I will only insert or delete using other keys.

Comment: It's hard to understand why you don't think you need a unique key.  Please explain why your primary key isn't just the combination of `receipt_id`, `prod_id` and `coupon_id`.  It looks like what you're getting at is this being a **compound primary key**.  Are you asking whether you need to add a _surrogate_ key?

Comment: The combination of `receipt_id`, `prod_id`, and `coupon_id` won't be unique. And I don't think I need a unique key, because I won't use it in any of my query. So I wan't to know if the primary is essential for mysql itself.

Comment: Show us the important `SELECTs`.  From them, we can deduce what indexes are important.  [_More info_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM receipt_line WHERE receipt_id = ?` or `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM receipt_line WHERE prod_id = ?` or `SELECT * FROM receipt_line WHERE coupon_id = ? AND receipt_id = ?`As I said, I will never use the primary. But as Karoly explained it to me, this primary will be automaticly created by Inodb if I won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things which are important in your case about primary keys in InnoDB:

1. The records are stored in a B+Tree on the Primary Key
2. Every single secondary indexes will have your primary key appended to them

Downsides of not having a single auto-increment PK:

- With a larger natural key you lose a lot of space on your secondary indexes which I see you will have a lot.
- Because the primary key is not in a continuous incremental number page splits will happen more frequently -> slower insert time and more fragmentation which again will increase your tablespace size even though the net size might be smaller.

Downsides of having auto-increment PK:

- Secondary index lookups might be slower but with adaptive hash index it is managed quite well.

Using InnoDB the rule of thumb is always use auto_increment primary key and only deviate from this rule if you explicitly want to and know why you're deviating. What you may save with that 4 or 8 bytes / row you will lose more on fragmentation and bigger index size.

The only time you really benefit from a larger composite or natural primary key is if that's the *only* way you query the table. If any other secondary indexes comes into play it's better to have that single column autoinc PK.

Comment: Thanks, but my question wasn't about using an auto-increment pk OR a natural key. It was about not using a primary at all...

Comment: About your description of the primary key in InnoDB. How are the records stored in the B+Tree when there is no Primary Key ?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear on that. Sorry! In InnoDB there's always a primary key. Even if you don't specify one InnoDB will create a "hidden" one for you and the same rules applies.

Comment: Ok, that's intersting ! And how does InnoDB choose the length of this hidden key ?

Comment: If you have unique key(s) then the first one which only has not null columns will be used. Otherwise Innodb will create a 6 byte continuously incrementing ROW_ID (like auto_increment). Detailed info can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: I mark your answer as correct, but the real answer is in your last comment. Thank you very much ! By the way, do you know what happens if the number of rows is longer than 6 bytes ?

Answer (score 1):

If the records needs to be unique, then it is up to you to either pick a composite key (multiple columns) to make them unique, or use a primary key (unique by definition). I don't think there is anything more efficient. If the concern is running out of bigint values, [you won't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762327/what-if-i-need-a-very-very-big-autoincrement-id). Knowing now that you will **never** query or join on this table seems shortsighted.

EDIT After More Info: If some combination of the receipt_id, prod_id and coupon_id are unique then you can just use that to establish uniqueness with a compound/composite primary key and dump the bigint id.

Comment: The records doesn't needs to be unique. Actually, they won't. I'm not afraid of running out of bigint value. I'm afraid of using a bigint, as it take a lot of space. If I'm not wrong, the difference between an int and a bigint in a 1 billion record table is 11GO.

Actually, I will query or join this table, but never on the primary. There is other keys I will use for that.

Comment: @Matthieu show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement, please. Are there other columns that have UNIQUE constraints?